# How do I animate opacity using swift?

Tags: swift, uiimageview, core-animation, cabasicanimation, nsvalue

Could someone please provide me with an example of animating the opacity of an Image View in swift??

I couldn't even find a good example in objective c

```
func showCorrectImage(element: AnyObject){

    var animation : CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity");

    animation.delegate = self

    animation.fromValue = NSValue(nonretainedObject: 0.0)
    animation.toValue = NSValue(nonretainedObject: 1.0)

    animation.duration = 1.0

    element.layer?.addAnimation(animation, forKey: nil)
}
```

I think I have most of this right (not completely sure though), could someone please help me?

element = an Image View

Thanks in advance!~

Answer (score 15):

If you need a simple animation, why not just use UIView's `animateWithDuration:animations:` method?

```
imageView.alpha = 0
UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0) {
        imageView.alpha = 1
}
```

Comment: @PugLvr28 Looks like you're new here. You should accept Swipesight's answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 10):

You can also write it like this:

```
animation.fromValue = 0.0
animation.toValue = 1.0
```

The whole code should be like this:

```
let animation = CABasicAnimation(#keyPath(CALayer.opacity))
animation.fromValue = 0.0
animation.toValue = 1.0
animation.duration = 1.0
animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: .easeInEaseOut)
element.layer?.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "fade")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this extension method (unless you want to modify the [`view`'s attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26995924/649379) itself):

```
extension CALayer {

    func flash(duration: TimeInterval) -> Observable<Void> {
        let flash = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")

        flash.fromValue = NSNumber(value: 0)
        flash.toValue = NSNumber(value: 1)
        flash.duration = duration
        flash.autoreverses = true

        removeAnimation(forKey: "flashAnimation")
        add(flash, forKey: "flashAnimation")
        opacity = 0     // Change the actual data value in the layer to the final value
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is looking to use CABasicAnimation like OP had originally tried to do, one problem with his original code was he was using NSValue for the toValue.  I switched it to NSNumber and it worked for me.  Like this

```
    fadeToVisible.fromValue = NSNumber(float: 0.0)
```